# Recursive Function equation

Tags: c, recursion

Forewarning, this is a homework assignment.
I am supposed to create a recursive function but I am doing this wrong. When I enter a 4 I am supposed to get a result of 16 from f(x) but I get -2. I don't really understand where I went wrong. Also I don't know if I am supposed to print my results inside of main or in f.

Write a program that queries the user for an integer value and uses a recursive

function that returns the value of the following recursive definition:

> ```
> f(x) =x+3 if x <=0
>
> f(x)=f(x-3)+(x+5) otherwise
> ```

My attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int f(int x); //Prototype to call to f

int main(void) {
  int n; //number the user will input

//Ask user to input data an reads it
  printf("Enter a whole number: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

//Pointer for f
  f(n);

//Prints results
  printf("\nn is %d\n", n);
  printf("f(x) is %d\n", f(n));
  return 0;
}

int f(int x) {
//Checks if equal to zero
  if (x <= 0) {
     x + 3;
  }
//If not equal to zero then do this
  else {
     f(x - 3) + (x + 5);
  }
}
```

Thank you all for the help, learned a lot from your comments and suggestions.
I was able to get it work I believe https://pastebin.com/v9cZHvy0

Comment: Every recursive function has (1) an exit condition, and (2) a recursive call. You provide no exit condition. Further, you need `scanf("%d", &n)` (note the `'&'`) and you must validate the **return**, e.g. `if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) { /* handle error */ }`. Your call to `f(n);` is not a `// Pointer for f` it is simply a function call (that makes little sense there). Think through how your set of recursive calls must exit. As it is the computation of `(x-3)+(x+5)` grows in size so `x <= 0` cannot be the exit condition.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: The exit condition is `x <= 0`. It seems you may have missed the fact that `f(x-3)` calls `f` and `(x+5)` does not.

Comment: Yes, I read it as `f (x-3 + x + 5)`.

Answer (score 2):

as far as I can see first one is `scanf`

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

second one is your function `f` is not returning anything, so this

```
int f(int x) {
//Checks if equal to zero
  if (x <= 0)
  {
     return (x + 3);
  }

  return ( f(x-3) + (x+5) );
}
```

minor - the below statement is actually useless

```
//Pointer for f
  f(n);
```

Comment: The additional `return ( ... )` parenthesis are superfluous, but good call on the function setup.

Answer (score 0):

As a student of life, I am always willing to help a fellow academic:

Your code has a few errors that should be of note:

1. `int f(int x)` has no return statement, even though it is expecting an integer. I assume you wish to return the result of the program (See Issue #3).
2. You execute f(n) twice. First on line 12, then again on line 16. `printf("f(x) is %d\n", f(n));` actually executes F(n) in order to receive its return value to associate with the %d format specifier.
3. You have not assigned `x+3` OR `f(x-3) + (x+5)` to any integer. These statements do not save the return values of f(x) that you need to return.

This link may be of help to you:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-function-argument-return-values/

Notice specifically how the output of functions are captured.

Hope this helps (And I wish you academic success!)

Comment: Also, the `scanf` statement misses a `&`